# How to do this C# return statement in Java

Tags: java, c#, .net

I will like to know if there is a way to do the second or third return statement in Java

Example using C#:

I have this class with properties

```
class Properties
{
    public int ResponseCode { get; set; }

    public string ResponseMessage { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Academics { get; set; }
}
```

I did it like this at the beginning:

```
    public static Properties CreateStudentFirstWay()
    {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.Name = "Michael";
        properties.Academics = "Information";
        properties.ResponseCode = 0000;
        properties.ResponseMessage = "Created";
        return properties;
    }
```

I use this from time to time

```
    public static Properties CreateStudentSecondWay()
    {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        {
            Name = "Michael",
            Academics = "Information",
            ResponseCode = 0000,
            ResponseMessage = "Created"
        };

        return properties;
    }
```

And recently I have been doing it like this

```
    public static Properties CreateStudentThirdWay()
    {
        return new Properties()
        {
            Name = "Michael",
            Academics = "Information",
            ResponseCode = 0000,
            ResponseMessage = "Created"
        };
    }
```

We are able to do the last one in C# without a constructor, without a builder or even without the need to populate all the properties in the class.

Is there a way to accomplished this in Java without the need of a constructor or the builder?

Thanks!

Comment: Builder Design Pattern .. to go

Comment: @madreflection _Never_ use "double brace". The "side effects" are catastrophic in all sorts of cases.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike-: Point taken. I'm not a Java developer; it just looked like a possible duplicate, as the syntax looked very similar. I retracted the close vote based on your assertion. Probably not the place for this question, but how something so problematic even get into the language?

Comment: @madreflection No worries, and I'd have re-opened. ;-) It's not that there's something "problematic in the language", it's simply abuse of a language feature (anonymous subclasses, which are used for strategy handlers and the like) to instead subclass a value type and apply no changes except adding initializer code--which nevertheless creates _a different class_ with all the attendant problems. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-operator-in-c

Answer (score 0):

Java does not support this syntax; you have to use a variable and call the various `set` methods. Groovy does have a syntax that provides this:

```
public static Properties createStudent() {
    return new Properties(
        name: "Michael",
        academics: "Information",
        responseCode: 0,
        responseMessage: "created"
    )
}
```

but if you want to do this with Java you'll need either a constructor with arguments or a builder. Lombok's `@AllArgsConstructor` can generate one for you.